# Помогите с RuntimeException. Входной массив должен содержать хотя бы одну четверку, иначе в методе необходимо выбросить RuntimeException Java

Tags: java

```
public class NewArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sourceArray = {1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 7};
        resultArray(sourceArray);
    }

    public static void resultArray(int[] sourceArray) {`введите сюда код`
        // Искомое число
        int searchedNumber = 4;

        // Получаем числа из массива после искомого числа в обратном порядке
        int[] reverseArray = IntStream.range(0, sourceArray.length)
                // Обходим индексы массива в обратную сторону
                .map(i -> sourceArray.length - 1 - i)
                // Элементы массива
                .map(i -> sourceArray[i])
                // Пока не встретили искомый элемент
                .takeWhile(i -> i != searchedNumber)
                // Выгружаем в массив
                .toArray();

        // Разворачиваем массив
        int[] resultArray = IntStream.range(0, reverseArray.length)
                // Обходим индексы массива в обратную сторону
                .map(i -> reverseArray.length - 1 - i)
                // Элементы массива
                .map(i -> reverseArray[i])
                // Выгружаем в массив
                .toArray();
        // Выводим результат
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: а что должен вернуть метод , если четверка есть? например, для вашего случая : {1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 7};

Comment: Дмитрий, задача в основе своей решена.

Comment: Написать метод, которому в качестве аргумента передается не пустой одномерный целочисленный массив. Метод должен вернуть новый массив, который получен путем вытаскивания из исходного массива элементов, идущих после последней четверки. Входной массив должен содержать хотя бы одну четверку, иначе в методе необходимо выбросить RuntimeException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

стрим умеет бросать исключение, а для копирования массива не нужен второй стрим.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class NewArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int searchedNumber = 4;
        int[] sourceArray = {1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 7};
        int[] result = resultArray(sourceArray, searchedNumber);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public static int[] resultArray(int[] sourceArray, int searchedNumber) {
        
        int index = IntStream.range(0, sourceArray.length)
                .map(i -> sourceArray.length - 1 - i)
                .filter(i->sourceArray[i]==searchedNumber)
                .findFirst().orElseThrow(()->new RuntimeException());
        
        int[] result = new int[sourceArray.length-index-1];
        System.arraycopy(sourceArray, index+1, result, 0, sourceArray.length-index-1);
        return result;
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int firstIndex = IntStream.range(0, sourceArray.length)
        .filter(i -> searchedNumber == sourceArray[i])
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(-1);`введите сюда код`
    
if(firstIndex == -1)
    throw new RuntimeException("Массив должен содержать минимум 1 четверку");
```

Answer (score 0):

Например можно сделать так:

```
int firstIndex = IntStream.range(0, sourceArray.length)
        .filter(i -> searchedNumber == sourceArray[i])
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(-1);
    
if(firstIndex == -1)
    throw new RuntimeException("Массив должен содержать минимум 1 четверку");
```

То есть мы находим индекс первого вхождения `searchedNumber` в массиве `sourceArray`. Если такого элемента в массиве нет, то возвращаем `-1`. Ну а дальше проверку просто делаем. По факту код выше это аналог функции `indexOf`.

Comment: Спасибо, Павел. Задача Решена!)))